# Update object inside array in useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this `cart` state in which the initial value is an empty array `[]`.

const [cart,setCart] = useState([]);

This is how one of my product `object` looks like,

```
{id: 1, name: 'Shoe pair', price: 40}
```

There is an `add to cart` button for each product. So when the `add to cart` button is clicked `addToCart` function is triggered,

```
const addToCart = (item) => {
  let initialItem = {id: item.id, name: item.name, quantity: 1} 
  let existingItem = cart.filter(cartItem => item.id === cartItem.id);
  if(existingItem.length > 0){
    existingItem.quantity = existingItem.quantity + 1;
  } else {
    setCart(crr => [...crr, initialItem ]);
  }
}
```

**What does addToCart do?**
As you can see it is simple.First, it creates an object by setting the initial quantity to 1. If already the same product is present in the cart it updates the quantity in the cart product by 1 else the initialItem being added to the cart.

To monitor this occurrence I used `useEffect` hook,

```
useEffect(() => {
 console.log(cart);
}, [cart]);
```

My problem is I can't see the cart in the console log when the quantity updates by 1 , But it shows when the initialItem is being pushed to the cart.

Comment: existingItem is an array (because it was created by cart.filter), thereby it has no `.quantity` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First issue: It is `find`, not `filter`.

Next issue - modifying item inside of array will not tell React that array is changed, you need to re-set state after existing item update also.

```
const addToCart = (item) => {
  const initialItem = { id: item.id, name: item.name, quantity: 1 };
  const existingItem = cart.find((cartItem) => item.id === cartItem.id);
  if (existingItem) {
    existingItem.quantity += 1;
    setCart((curr) => [...curr]);
  } else {
    setCart((curr) => [...curr, initialItem]);
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer easy to understand

Answer (score 2):

The reason your `useEffect` is not running when you think it should, is because its dependency is not being updated when you think it is. It will run when `setCart` is called and the reference to `cart` is updated, and then you will see your console log.

`filter` returns a new array -- will not mutate the original array.
docs -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

`find` returns the item by reference, if found -- otherwise returns `undeifined`.
docs -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Alternate example:

```
const addToCart = (item) => {
  const existingItem = cart.find(i => i.id === item.id)
  const updatedCart = existingItem
    ? cart.map(i => {
        return i.id === item.id ? {...i, quantity: i.quantity + 1} : i
      })
    : [...cart, item]
  }
  setCart(updatedCart)
}
```